# Setting theorem environment fonts when using multiple fonts with unicode-math

Tags: fonts, unicode-math, amsthm

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[version=xcharter]{XCharter Math}
\setmathfont[version=fira]{Fira Math}
\newfontfamily\xcharterfont{XCharter}
\newfontfamily\firafont{Fira Sans}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
    \xcharterfont \mathversion{xcharter}
    Some text. \(123 \alpha a \text{a}\)
    \begin{theorem}
        This is a theorem. \(\alpha = 1, 2\).
    \end{theorem}
    \firafont \mathversion{fira}
    Some text. \(123 \alpha a \text{a}\)
    \begin{theorem}
        This is a theorem. \(\alpha = 1, 2\).
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

This generates the following output when compiled with XeLaTeX (no warnings or errors).

[image: output]

I want XCharter fonts to be used for Theorem 1 and Fira Sans for Theorem 2. How do I get them? Why are LM fonts used in both the cases (for text) instead of XCharter and Fira?

Answer (score 1):

The `amsthm` package issues `\normalfont` in some places, but you want to keep the current family.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\setmathfont[version=xcharter]{XCharter-Math.otf}
\setmathfont[version=fira]{Fira Math}
\newfontfamily\xcharterfont{XCharter}
\newfontfamily\firafont{Fira Sans}

% patch the amsthm commands to replace \normalfont
% with a similar command that reinstates the current font family
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@thm}{\normalfont}{\apoorv@keepcurrentfamily}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\deferred@thm@head}{\normalfont}{\apoorv@keepcurrentfamily}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\th@definition}{\normalfont}{\apoorv@keepcurrentfamily}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\th@remark}{\normalfont}{\apoorv@keepcurrentfamily}{}{}
\newcommand{\apoorv@keepcurrentfamily}{%
  \expandafter\normalfont\expandafter\fontfamily\expandafter{\f@family}\selectfont
}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}

\begin{document}

\xcharterfont \mathversion{xcharter}
Some text. \(123 \alpha a \text{a}\)

\begin{definition}
This is a \emph{definition}
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem. \(\alpha = 1, 2\).
\end{theorem}

\begin{remark}
This is a remark.
\end{remark}

\firafont \mathversion{fira}
Some text. \(123 \alpha a \text{a}\)

\begin{definition}
This is a \emph{definition}
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem. \(\alpha = 1, 2\).
\end{theorem}

\begin{remark}
This is a remark.
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can I do the same for proofs? I, unfortunately, do not understand how the normal font is being replaced due to a lack of knowledge. So, just by analogy, I tried adding `\xpatchcmd{\th@proof}{\normalfont}{\apoorv@keepcurrentfamily}{}{}`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: In short, I want the fonts selected by `\<fontname>font` to be applied for all environments; all the text and math before a new font is selected. It would be preferable if there is any global command that does this instead of changing fonts for each environment manually.

Comment: Ah, I just found out that one can use the `\setmainfont` command outside the preamble as well. This solves my issue. Although it would have been nice if `\setmainfont` had support for 'versions', similar to `\setmathfont`.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis I'd recommend against resetting the main font inside the document.

Comment: Are there any particular reasons for that?